# rmagick problem on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, rmagick

I am trying to install rmagick on Windows for a rails app.

I've downloaded the following file and followed the instructions:
http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/64917/RMagick-2.12.0-ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8.zip

If I run irb and `require 'rubygems'; require 'RMagick'`, it's ok.
But if I `require 'RMagick'` in rails console, it gives me the following error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'RMagick'
LoadError: no such file to load -- RMagick
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.
0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.
0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.
0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.
0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.
0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.
0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from (irb):1
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisites:
Ruby > 1.8.6
DevKit (any version)
No other ImageMagick installation or PATH entry

Step 1:
Installing ImageMagick:

Download ImageMagick:
http://imagemagick.spd.co.il/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.0-3-Q16-windows-dll.exe

Install ImageMagick:
*Important: The installation path should NOT contain any spaces.
Ideally select “C:\ImageMagick″

Please make sure to select the below options:

> Add application directory to your path system
>   Install development headers and libraries for C and C++

Step 2:
Installing rmagick:

Use the following command to install rmagick gem:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include
```

via-

http://shoobm.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/installing-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7/